# Integrate product of polynomials

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integration-by-parts

I am trying to compute the integral $\int_0^1 p^x(1-p)^{n-x+1} dp$ using integration by parts, however, I am stuck in a loop where I keep computing integrals of products of polynomials (of higher order than the originals).

Is there a general method to compute such integrals?

Comment: Eulerian integral?

Comment: Yes, thank you. How can I show, by hand, that the solution is the Beta function?

Comment: What is your definition of the beta function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the exponents are integers the integration by parts should terminate.  The standard convention for the exponents in the integral ("Eulerian Integral of the First Kind") would be $\int _0^1 {x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}dx}$.  Letting $u=x^{m-1}$ and $dv=(1-x)^{n-1}dx$ for an integration by parts gives $$\int _0^1 {x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}dx}= \frac{m-1}{n} \int _0 ^1 {x^{m-2}(1-x)^{n}dx}$$  Proceeding inductively after (m-1) intgegration by parts $$\int _0^1 {x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}dx}= \frac{(m-1)(m-2)\cdot\cdot\cdot2\cdot1}{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdot\cdot\cdot(n+m-2)} \int _0 ^1 {(1-x)^{n+m-2}dx}$$  After evaluating the last integral $$\int _0^1 {x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}dx}= \frac{(m-1)(m-2)\cdot\cdot\cdot2\cdot1}{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdot\cdot\cdot(n+m-1)}=\frac{(m-1)!\space (n-1)!}{(n+m-1)!}$$  The latter expression defines the Beta function $B (m,n)$.